# DateTime is being interpreted as two different formats

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application which allows appointment booking.  The user can click on a slot in the diary view, which takes them to a page to select the practitioner and confirm.

The query string for this page contains a DateTime which is the time the appointment is to start.  This is automatically formatted in US format by Html.ActionLink(...), like so:

/assign?date=04%2F06%2F2011%2009%3A00%3A00

This is correctly deserialised and the view reports that the appointment time will be the 6th of April.  It is also stored in a hidden field in the view to be posted to the confirm action; the hidden field has the value: 04/06/2011 09:00:00, rendered by Html.HiddenFor(...).  Again, looks like US format.

However, when the form gets posted, the appointment is booked for the 4th of June, presumably interpreting the date as en-GB.

Why would it do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might happen because your server is configured to auto detect the culture of the browser and if the browser preferred  culture is en-GB that's what the server will use when binding DateTime parameters:

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
```

You could specify it to a fixed culture:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
```